# XPath to locate element based on attribute value?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to search a XML document I created but I can't seem to get it to work properly. Here is my XML document...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<states>
<repstate location="AL">
    <compName>Test Company</compName>
    <name>Chris Brown</name>
    <address>123 Main St</address>
    <city>Anytown</city>
    <state>CT</state>
    <phone>203-123-4567</phone>
    <fax>203-456-7890</fax>
    <email>info@email.com</email>
    <website>www.testing.com</website>
    <serviceArea>All of Alabama</serviceArea>
</repstate>
<repstate location="AK">
    <compName>Test Company</compName>
    <name>Chris Brown</name>
    <address>123 Main St</address>
    <city>Anytown</city>
    <state>CT</state>
    <phone>203-123-4567</phone>
    <fax>203-456-7890</fax>
    <email>info@email.com</email>
    <website>www.testing.com</website>
    <serviceArea>All of Alabama</serviceArea>
</repstate>
</states>
```

and here is the code snippet i'm trying to get to work...

```
        <?php 
            $xml = simplexml_load_file('../../usa.xml');
            $found = $xml->xpath("//@location='AK'");
            echo $found->state;
        ?>
```

It doesn't seem to be working properly.

I'm trying to load the information in that node. So all the compName, name, address, city, state, phone, fax, email, website and serviceArea. I thought it would be easy to just get "state" working but nothing seems to output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Micheal Kay* has outlined in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32661344/367456), the xpath expression is valid. What he does not know is that for SimpleXML this won't lead into an empty result.

So you see a fatal error as you try to read a field from an empty array. Your code works similar to this one:

```
$found = array();
echo $found->state;
```

Which echoes an empty string (created out of the `NULL` value that expression give) and a notice:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...

If you don't see yet this notice, it's crucial you enable error messages with your development system, see *[How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)*.

So as you can see, it is working properly, it just does not provide what you expect. To go on with that in a more productive manner for yourself, it would have been great if you would have shared what exactly you did expect instead.

Or in other words: As others have answered as well, you need to decide what you're looking for.

From the output code:

```
echo $found->state;
```

I'd say you're looking for the following XML element:

```
...
<repstate location="AK">
    <compName>Test Company</compName>
    <name>Chris Brown</name>
    <address>123 Main St</address>
    <city>Anytown</city>
    <state>CT</state>
    ...
```

So here is how SimpleXML Xpath works:

1. you can only query lists of nodes
2. the only nodes supported are elements and attributes
3. the list is always of type array
4. the array is always zero-indexed
5. each entry in the array - if the array is not empty - is of type **SimpleXMLElement**

So in your case if my assumption of the element to query you expect to get is correct, you want the state child-element's node value of a single element node returned. The according PHP code then would be:

```
$list = $xml->xpath("//repstate[@location = 'AK']");
list($repstate) = $list + array(null);
$state = $repstate ? $repstate->state : '- no such location -';

echo $state;
```

The output with your XML then would be:

> CT

Or even shorter:

```
$list = $xml->xpath("//repstate[@location = 'AK']/state");
list($state) = $list + array('- no such location -');

echo $state;
```

I hope this more expansive explanation is helpful for you. The reason why your original expression does not work is that it's already violating the first point:

1. you can only query lists of nodes

because your xpath query represented a boolean expression and not a node-list. Additionally such a list in SimpleXMLElement xpath would need you to have an element or attribute and *not* a boolean expression.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% positive on this, but in c# the xPath would be:   
//repstate[@location='AK'] 
so you can try that (I can't put that in a comment as I don't have a high enough reputation :))

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what you want your XPath expression to do. Your expression is valid, it will return a boolean which will be true if there is an `@location` attribute equal to "AK" anywhere in the document.

If you want to find the element that has an `@location` attribute equal to "AK", use `//*[@location='AK']`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `xpath`-expression itself, `xpath` will return an **`array`** of `SimpleXML` elements to `$found`, so...

```
echo $found[0]->state;
```

or - with PHP >= 5.4 - you can de-reference the array like this:

```
$found = $xml->xpath(...)[0];
echo $found->state;
```

see it here: https://eval.in/435965